# Equation not fully solved for

Tags: maxima

I've been trying to solve an equation for a 2D vector P.
But after `solve` there are still some P on the rhs.
Does this mean Maxima can't do it or I've done something wrong?

Here is it:

```
load("vect");
declare(".", commutative);

declare(P, nonscalar);
declare([v1,V1,r1], nonscalar);
declare([v2,V2,r2], nonscalar);
declare([w1,W1,m1,I1,w2,W2,m2,I2], scalar);

/* Revolute Constraint */
constraint: v2 + (w2~r2) - (v1 + (w1~r1)) = 0$

/* Velocities after impulse P */
eq1: v1 = V1 - P/m1$
eq2: w1 = W1 - (r1~P) / I1$
eq3: v2 = V2 + P/m2$
eq4: w2 = W2 + (r2~P) / I2$

eq: subst([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4], constraint)$
solve(eq, P);
```

(I'm trying to get an equation for an impulse that satisfies the constraint.
I'm following Dirk Gregorius' 2nd post here: https://gamedev.net/forums/topic/469531-revolute-joint-usingimpulses/4086845)

Comment: `solve` won't know what to do with the cross products -- to make progress with `solve` I think you'll have to expand the expression into terms involving coordinates, i.e. write P = `[P[1], P[2]]`, likewise with any other vectors, expand the whole thing (I think there are options in `vect` for that), and then solve for `P[1]` and `P[2]`.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier for helping out. I have posted a follow up taking in your advice, to now unexpand it.

Comment: On looking at this again, I see a couple of things. The less important is that I see `express` automatically substitutes `[a[x], a[y], a[z]]` for `a` when `a` is declared `nonscalar`, so I guess maybe it's not necessary to do it by hand. The more important is that seems like it should be possible to work out a solution for `eq` by using matrix algebra. I think you can write a cross product `a ~ b` as a matrix-vector multiplication, `a ~ b = A . b` where `A` is `matrix([0, -a[z], a[y]], [a[z], 0, -a[x]], [-a[y], a[x], 0])` (I think I got that right).

Comment: I think then you can use that to rearrange `eq` to be something like `stuff + matrix . P + anothermatrix . P + yetanother . P = 0` (rearrange any `P ~ a` to `- a ~ P`), so the result you want is going to be `P = (matrix + another + yetanother)^^-1 . stuff` more or less. It seems likely an explicit solution of that will be kind of messy, which I think you've already seen. Maybe if you just need to paste it into a program or something, neatness is less important, but that depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've worked out the details. I had to do some stuff by hand, and Maxima was mostly just checking that I did it correctly. If the goal is just to get to a solution, I guess that's okay.

Here's my script. You can execute this via: `maxima --batch=foo.mac` where `foo.mac` is the name of the script.

```
/* adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69700162/equation-not-fully-solved
 */

load("vect");

/* I don't want to reorder arguments of cross product. */
remrule ("~", ?\~rule4);

/* I do want to flatten noncommutative multiplication.
 * (It appears that's disabled by vect; ordinarily it happens by default.)
 */
dotassoc: true $

declare(P, nonscalar);
declare([v1,w1,V1,W1,r1], nonscalar);
declare([v2,w2,V2,W2,r2], nonscalar);
declare([m1,I1,m2,I2], scalar);

/* Revolute Constraint */
constraint: v2 - (r2~w2) - (v1 - (r1~w1)) = 0$

/* Velocities after impulse P */
eq1: v1 = V1 - P/m1$
eq2: w1 = W1 - (r1~P) / I1$
eq3: v2 = V2 + P/m2$
eq4: w2 = W2 + (r2~P) / I2$

eq: subst([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4], constraint);

A(a) := matrix([0, -a[3], a[2]], [a[3], 0, -a[1]], [-a[2], a[1], 0]);

eqa: ev (eq, (u~v) := 'A(u).v);

matchdeclare (pp, lambda ([e], not freeof(P, e)));
matchdeclare (qq, lambda ([e], freeof(P, e)));
defrule (rp, pp + qq = 0, pp = -qq);

eqa1: expand (eqa);
eqa2: apply1 (eqa1, rp);

matchdeclare (aa, lambda ([e], matrixp(e) or listp(e)));
tellsimpafter (I(aa), ident (length (aa)));

matchdeclare ([aa, bb], all);
tellsimpafter (I(aa) . bb, bb);
tellsimpafter (aa . I(bb), aa);

M: -(1/I2)*'A(r2).'A(r2) - (1/I1)*'A(r1).'A(r1) + (1/m2)*I(P) + (1/m1)*I(P);
N: 'A(r2).W2 - 'A(r1).W1 - V2 + V1;

eqa2_factored: M . P = N;

expand (eqa2_factored);
?resimplify (%);
if % # eqa2 then error ("tried to factor eqa2, but something went wrong.");

solution: P = M^^-1 . N;

/* EXAMPLE: */

I1: 20 $
I2: 3 $
m1: 100 $
m2: 12 $
V1: [17, 19, -23] $
V2: [-5, -3, 11] $
W1: [8, 4, 14] $
W2: [-6, -16, 24 ] $
r1: [1/2, 2/3, 3/4] $
r2: [5, 7, 3] $

/* note various subterfuges to ensure evaluation with stated values */

example_M: ev (subst (I(P) = ident(3), M), nouns);
example_N: ev (N, nouns);

example_P: example_M^^-1 . example_N;

subst (P = example_P, ev (eqa2, eval, nouns));

if lhs(%) = rhs(%)
    then print ("TEST PASSED: lhs = rhs")
    else error ("TEST FAILED: lhs # rhs");
```

If you need to evaluate `P` for different parameters `r1`, `r2`, etc., my advice is to evaluate matrix `M` and vector `N` with whatever values you want to plug in, and then solve the equation `P = M^^-1 . N`. An explicit solution is probably going to be pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

Following Robert Dodier's advice, I broke up all the vectors and solved for P[1] and P[2] individually.
I've got something that gives me an answer but now how can I get it into nice vector form?
Here it is:

```
load("vect");
declare(".", commutative);

declare(P, nonscalar);
declare([v1,V1,r1], nonscalar);
declare([v2,V2,r2], nonscalar);
declare([w1,W1,m1,I1], scalar);
declare([w2,W2,m2,I2], scalar);

cross_scalar_vector(s,v) := [-s*v[2], s*v[1]]$
/* Revolute Constraint on Linear Velocity */
constraint: v2 + cross_scalar_vector(w2,r2) - (v1 + cross_scalar_vector(w1,r1)) = [0,0]$

/* Sub in velocities after impulse P. */
post_velocities: [
    v1 = V1 - P/m1,
    w1 = W1 - (r1~P) / I1,
    v2 = V2 + P/m2,
    w2 = W2 + (r2~P) / I2
]$
constraint: subst(post_velocities, constraint)$

/* Break up the remaining vectors for solve. */
vectors: [
    P = [P[1], P[2]],
    V1 = [V1[1], V1[2]],
    r1 = [r1[1], r1[2]],
    V2 = [V2[1], V2[2]],
    r2 = [r2[1], r2[2]]
]$
constraint: subst(vectors, constraint)$

/* Break up vector constraint into x and y constraint for solve. */
xconstraint: lhs(constraint)[1] = 0$
yconstraint: lhs(constraint)[2] = 0$

/* Not sure why we need to do this again? */
xconstraint: subst(vectors, xconstraint)$
yconstraint: subst(vectors, yconstraint)$

/* Expand cross products for solve. */
xconstraint: express(xconstraint)$
yconstraint: express(yconstraint)$

solve([xconstraint,yconstraint], [P[1],P[2]]);
```